# how to use cypress for if..then test flow

Tags: typescript, mocha.js, cypress

I want to write some test in cypress to load page and check if some modal is opened (that should not take more than 5 seconds) then close it, otherwise if modal does not opened, just go to testcase in before block. How can I do it? so far I have following code, and I can only make sure if modal exist then it close.

```
function checkModalThenProceed() {
  cy.get(#check modal is open function).then(($modal) => {
    if ($modal) {
      closedModal();
    }
  })
}
describe('test if-else flow', () => {
  before(()=>{
    checkModalThenProceed();
  })
  it('testflow', () => {
    expect(1).to.eq(1);
  });
})
``
```

Comment: If you want to conditionally run a test based on an element or DOM, you need to use jQuery to select those elements and figure out what you want. If you use `cy.get()` it's actually running a test. A `cy.get()` that returns nothing counts as a failed test.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit hard to guess what **#check modal is open function** represents, but if it's a function as the name implies then you can just call it and use the result directly in a simple `if()` statement.

Since that is obvious, and you have a `cy.get()`, I assume you are using a selector of some kind.

Using `cy.get()` in that scenario will fail the test whenever the modal is not actually open.

You can change the expression to use jquery (provided on the Cypress global as `Cypress.$`, [ref](https://docs.cypress.io/api/utilities/$.html)), which allows you to test the selector without causing the test to fail, see [jquery ref](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-test-whether-an-element-exists/).

```js
function checkModalThenProceed() {
  if (Cypress.$('my-modal-selector').length) {  // zero length means not found
    closedModal();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this code:

```
if ($body.find("modal_selector").length > 0) {   
        //evaluates as true if selector exists at all
        //do something
        .....
      }else{
           //if selector does not exist
           }
```